# Container in Media Query

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make it so when I view this page on mobile, the container will fit the screen.

```
<h3 style="text-align: center; margin-left: 100px; padding-top: 30px;">Latest Posts</h3>
<div class="a2c" style="background-color:black; margin: 40px 40px 80px 100px; width: 400px; height: 480px;">
    <div id="image" style="margin-top: 20px;">
      <a href="test.html">
      <img src="images/fix.jpg" style="width: 390px; height: 250px; display: flex; left: 0px;">
      </a>
    </div>
    <h3 style="text-align: center; margin-top: 20px;"><a href=test.html> Sample Text</h3></a>
    <p style="font-size: 15px; margin-top: 20px; margin-left: 10px; margin-right: 5px;">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. </p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use @media queries to adjust the styles with CSS and you'll probably want to refactor all of those inline styles with classes.

For example:

```
<style>
.title { text-align: center; margin-left: 100px; padding-top: 30px; }
.a2c { background-color: black; margin: 40px 40px 80px 100px; width: 400px; height: 480px; }
#image { margin-top: 20px; }
#image img { width: 390px; height: 250px; display: flex; left: 0px; }
/* ... */

/* now, add a media query below to override the previous styles for small screens */
@media (max-width: 600px) {
   .title { margin-left: 0; }
   .a2c { margin: 40px 0 80px 0; width: 100%; }
   #image img { width: 100%; }
}
</style>
```

Comment: I will give it a try. Thanks!